# SolrCloud insert/update documents

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

presently i am working on a search application using solrcloud. I have tested many features of solrcloud which i was looking for.I want to know that if i insert/update/delete in to cloud using solrj client (Any flavor Http,embedded,cloud ...) or using lucene API directly to write to index directory of any server in the solrcloud, will solrcloud distribute this change to across the all nodes in the cloud ?

Will solrcloud be able to detect these  changes made into its index?(cause i am not using RESt API)

can anyone explain, will be a lot helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an update come to a node in the cluster (it doesn't matter it comes from REST API or Solrj) it will automatically replicated to other nodes.

You can find good info about SolrCloud in [this document](http://searchhub.org/2012/05/21/solr-4-preview/).

Comment: Thanks parvin.can u please tell me in case of http or rest api call what happens if the node is down for which request was sent ? say for example http://192.168.100.1:8983/sole/collection/select.....what if 192.168.100.1 is down it self !

Comment: Read this document. It will answer your question. http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Read+and+Write+Side+Fault+Tolerance